# Ionic - Show Div 4 Secs after Page Load

Tags: html, ionic-framework, timer, show, hidden

In my html page I have a DIV inicialiced hidden:

```
<div [hidden]=“val>0”>
```

When run constructor, I define val=10, then the DIV is hidden.

then with a timer (after 4000ms) I change val to -1, so, the DIV should show, but notthing append.

```
startTimer(){ setTimeout(function(){ 
this.val=-1;
console.log(‘show!!’); },4000) 
}
```

In the console i can see ‘**show!!**’ writen, but the DIV still hidden.

I tried with boolean variable, NgIf, etc., but i get the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful when using anonymous functions and track where (which scope) “this” is pointing at.

Try using fat arrow function to prevent this to gain new scope:

startTimer(){ setTimeout(()=>{ 
this.val=-1;
console.log(‘show!!’); },4000) 
}

Comment: I'll try and let you know.

Thank you for your answer.